# scipy.optimize.root uses up all memory

Tags: python, memory, scipy

I am trying to solve an equation using `scipy`'s root. The problem is, that I quickly run out of memory if my problem requires many iterations. Using `pympler`'s `tracker`, I see that every function call reserves new memory which is never freed up again.

How can I find out, what prevents the memory from being freed up?

Comment: What is the function doing? Does it have any side effects - does it use any (global) variables other than the ones that are passed into it?

Comment: It's a very complicated problem, that's why I gave no minimal example. I use a `functools.partial` to supply all the argument's but the one which is optimized. The function has a side effect, an object is passed via `partial` and one of its attributes is modified. Furthermore, I pass the function a dict, to save some intermediate values, but removing the dict has no impact on memory. No global variables are used.

Comment: I still have no clue how to properly search for the memory waste. I however stumbled across a post warning about slices. The arrays basically referenced themselves, thus they could never be collected. My urgent problem is thus fixed.